# How do I display Youtube/Vimeo video ID on custom post type when user enters it in custom meta box?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, vimeo

I have created a 2x shortcodes that displays a youtube video and vimeo video when the user enters the videos id in it, for emample: [youtube id=""] [vimeo id=""].

Instead of entering this in my post I am trying to create a custom meta box that the user can enter the id in and then this is displayed.

So far I have been able to create a plugin to display the meta box but I'm not sure how to get it to save the youtube/vimeo ID and display the video.

Will I need 2x different meta boxes? One that the user can enter the youtube video ID in and the other where the vimeo ID can be entered and then this is displayed on the front end?

The code I have for the meta box is:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Enter Video ID', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'videos', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_text'][0] ) : '';

    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text">Youtube/Vimeo ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
    </p>


    <?php   
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set
    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'], $allowed ) );


}
?>
```

I also think I need to run a loop on my single-video.php template so that wordpress knows to display the ID from the custom meta box. For the loop this is all I have so far:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

That isnt finished though so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in correct way. You need to create metabox for selecting video_type it will youtube/vimeo. then you need to give one text box for adding id for respective video type.
code will look like as follows

```
<?php 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
 add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Enter Video ID', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'videos', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
$vedio_type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_vedio_type',true);
$vedio_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_text">Select vedio type:</label>
     <!-- added select for selecting vedio type -->
    <select name="my_vedio_type" id="my_vedio_type">  
        <option <?php echo ($vedio_type == 'youtube') ? "selected='selected'" : "" ;?> value="youtube">Youtube</option>
        <option <?php echo ($vedio_type == 'vimeo') ? "selected='selected'" : "" ;?> value="vimeo">Vimeo</option>
    </select>
    <!-- added select for selecting vedio type -->
</p>

<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_text">Youtube/Vimeo ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $vedio_id; ?>" />
</p>


<?php   
  }


 add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' ); 
 function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

// now we can actually save the data
$allowed = array( 
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
    )
);

// Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set
if( isset( $_POST['my_vedio_type'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_vedio_type', wp_kses( $_POST['my_vedio_type'], $allowed ) );
if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'], $allowed ) );


 }
 ?>
```

after that you can retrieve the these values using following code in custom post type single.php file

```
<?php 
 if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_vedio_type',true) == "youtube"){
 $youtube_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);     
  }
  if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_vedio_type',true) == "vimeo"){
 $vimeo_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);   
   }


   ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately when I put the code in single-video.php it doesnt display anything at all. This is my code in single-video.php: `code` <div class="page-content">
 <?php 
  if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_video_type',true) == "youtube"){
  $youtube_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);     
   }
   if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_video_type',true) == "vimeo"){
  $vimeo_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);   
  }


   ?>
</div>

Comment: can you check if it display any dummy text using these custom meta, if not there might be some issue. For example you can check $post->ID is returning id or not.

Comment: Do I need to put that in single-video.php? I added it but it didnt seem to make a difference. Is there any reason its not displaying anything? My code looks like: `code <?php global $post; ?>
<?php
      if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_video_type',true) == "youtube"){
       $youtube_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);     
       }
       if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_video_type',true) == "vimeo"){
        $vimeo_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);   
       }
       
      



   ?> `

Comment: In the back end I can see the custom meta box, dropdown and video ID field, for some reason on the front end nothing is displayed. When I use echo the_content(); it displays whats in the post but it doesnt display what is put into the meta box.

Comment: Im sorry @brasofilo where do I add that?

Comment: @NeelamKhan, anywhere. I'm just pointing that some meta keys have different names. Revise everything for typos.

Comment: Do I need to know the meta key to run this query? If so how do I find it? Sorry this is the first time im running a query that differs to the wordpress and I am a little confused.

Comment: Please once use this code and let me know
`<?php global $post; ?> <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_vedio_type',true) == "youtube"){ $youtube_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true); } if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_vedio_type',true) == "vimeo"){ $vimeo_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true); } ?> `

you can see I have changed my_video_type to my_vedio_type

Comment: just print the `get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true); ` and check what you got or check you got correct postid ...

Comment: When you enter the video id into the custom meta box I want wordpress to display the actual video from youtube/vimeo on the front end. At the moment it is displaying the id only which is not what I want it to do.